# Android app bundle error / Proguard-android-optimze.txt

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, bundle

Im trying to build a bundle for a new flutter app I made but i get this error

```
> Default file proguard-android-optimize.txt should not be specified in this module. It can be specified in the base module instead
```

Comment: Do you have a file called proguard-android-optimize.txt somewhere, and if yes where?

Comment: ..\build\app\intermediates\default_proguard_files\global